# Error in interactionR , why cant i fit a clogit model using survival package and pass it to the interactionR function

Tags: r

I am pretty new at R. Whenever I run the "interactionR" package with a fitted clogit model I receive the following errors/warnings:

1. Error in interactionR(clogit1, exposure_names = c("alcohol", "smoking"),  :
   Error: At least one exposure is preventive. Set argument recode=TRUE for the exposures to be automatically recoded. see Knol et al. (2011) European Journal of Epidemiology, 26(6), 433-438

--> changes argument recode = FALSE to recode = TRUE

2. Warning:In interactionR(clogit1, exposure_names = c("alcohol", "smoking"),  :
   Recoding exposures; new reference category for alcohol is 0 and for smoking is 1
3. Error in Surv(rep(1, 52L), case) : object 'case' not found
4. Error in interactionR_table(value2) : object 'value2' not found

I have tried the example dataset (OCdata) using glm instead of clogit, and that works. Pls, does anyone know whats wrong in my code? have done it over and over again, with the same errors. Also, i have tried interactionR_delta without success. In this example I used the VC1to1 dataset from the epiDisplay package. Since i have a matched case-control sample I would like to use the clogit model.

This is my code:

```
      library (survival)
      library(interactionR)
      library(epiDisplay)
      data(VC1to1)
      dataframe <- VC1to1

      # fit the interaction model: 
      clogit1 <- clogit(case ~ alcohol * smoking + 
      strata(matset), data = dataframe)
     

      # these first steps works fine. 

      ## pass the fitted model to the interactionR function, this is where it doesn´t work 
      ##anymore.
       interactionR(clogit1, exposure_names = c("alcohol", "smoking"), 
        ci.type = "delta", ci.level = 0.95, 
        em = FALSE, recode = TRUE)

     ### pass to value 
       value2 <- interactionR(clogit1, exposure_names = c("alcohol", "smoking"), 
                   ci.type = "delta", ci.level = 0.95, 
                   em = FALSE, recode = TRUE)

     ## use table function to generate a table 
      interactionR_table(value2)
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please make a reproducible example, so we can reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help you?

```
  library (survival)
  library(interactionR)
  library(epiDisplay)
  data(VC1to1)
  dataframe <- VC1to1

  # fit the interaction model: 
  clogit1 <- clogit(case ~ alcohol * smoking + 
  strata(matset), data = dataframe)
  clogit1$data = dataframe

  # these first steps works fine. 

  ## pass the fitted model to the interactionR function, this is where it doesn´t work 
  ##anymore.
   interactionR(clogit1, exposure_names = c("alcohol", "smoking"), 
    ci.type = "delta", ci.level = 0.95, 
    em = FALSE, recode = TRUE)

 ### pass to value 
   value2 <- interactionR(clogit1, exposure_names = c("alcohol", "smoking"), 
               ci.type = "delta", ci.level = 0.95, 
               em = FALSE, recode = TRUE)

 ## use table function to generate a table 
  interactionR_table(value2)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This helped, now the code is working.